# Can I show the normal characters instead of the regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the code I have:

```
$scope.currentTextClass = $scope.currentText1.replace(
    test5 = /<img .* \/>/g,
    "<div class=\"container\">" + test5.source + "</div>"
);
```

But the string of `test5.source` is `"<img .* \/>"`. What I want is the complete `img` tag instead of the raw regular expression.

Is it possible to return the original `img` tag?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense, try rewriting it and explain the problem

Comment: @Elena I've just answered the question as it makes perfect sense. I've edited the question to add some extra formatting, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the *source* of your regular expression is `<img .* \/>`. All `source` returns is the regular expression without the `/`s or flags (`g`, in this case).

> The source property returns a String containing the source text of the regexp object, and it doesn't contain the two forward slashes on both sides and any flags.
>
> — [MDN's notes on `RegExp.prototype.source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source)

If you want to access the full match, you can provide a function as the second parameter of your `replace` call. This itself has 3 arguments passed into it: the match, the position of the match, and the full text.

The first argument is what you want here:

```
$scope.currentTextClass = $scope.currentText1.replace(
    /<img .* \/>/g,
    function(match) {
        return "<div class=\"container\">" + match + "</div>";
    }
);
```

Comment: Seriously thanks a lot ! You don't know for how long I've been struggling with this problem and I even had problems with asking it, this was the 3th time I posted a question because people were hating. You derserve a lot of upvotes !

Comment: @Goldenowner no worries. I think the people who downvoted this probably haven't done much with the RegExp object's prototype properties and were confused by your use of `test5.source`.